# Where can I find a RPC which implemented with: boost + protobuf

Tags: c++, rpc, boost-asio, protocol-buffers

Are there any RPC framework implemented with: boost + protobuf? And it has a protobuf plugin can be used to generate RPC code for the framework.
Or there are some open source implementations I can refer to, please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: We have faced with a same problem (RPC based on boost::asio + protobuf). Did you manage to resolve it? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I recently find through a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092999/on-rcf-middleware-binary-size) that there is one : [RCF](http://deltavsoft.com) (Remote Call Framework)

It seems it can use `boost.asio` and `protocol buffers`. I have not used it myself.

my2c

Comment: I haven't used RCF with protobuf, but RCF in itself is a very good and cohesive framework, with a very clear seperation of transport layer versus serialization layer, I recommmend it.

Comment: @omer: Sounds good. I think I will give it a try next time I have to do that kind of thing. Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what one of my colleges had to build in a proprietary project (with a couple of extra cool stuff), so I can share his expert advise.

He believe you're out of luck and won't find that combo online...

However, if you're not in needed of a the specific format used by Protobuffs you can use **Thrift**.
Thrift is a product of a Facebook employee who once worked in Google, so its very similar to Protobuffs, and the main difference is exactly what you asked for-
Internal implementation using Boost,  and a built-in support for RPC transport layers and services.
The only problem is that currently there is no port of Thrift for Windows, but it works great for Linux.
Also you can check Protobuffs' Service option it doesn't give a lot but its a good place to start.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for your advise. If I can't find such a combination, I will implement one as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's this one.  I don't know if it's proper 'proactor' asio.

http://code.google.com/p/server1/